# Video.js Auto loading subtitles/captions

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js, captions

I'm doing a website and I need to show a player and I came out with video.js but I have a question how can I put my subtitles showing up without the user needing to click on anything?

This is my code:

```
<video id="filme" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="100%" height="640" data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="./video.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <track kind="subtitles" src="./subs/subtitles.srt" srclang="pt" label="Português" default>
</video>
```

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution.
You can check it at github, https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/656

This is the code that you should update on line 6666 and after.
Add this code:

```
if(track.dflt()) {
  this.player_.showTextTrack(this.track.id_, this.track.kind());
}
```

After this: (line 6676, as of v4.3)

```
 this.player_.on(track.kind() + 'trackchange', vjs.bind(this, this.update));
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

According to the **Video.js** documentation...

> Timed text requires a text file in **WebVTT** format.

Your current `track` is referencing an `.srt` file.

Try changing it to a `WebVTT`.

There is a builder here: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/CaptionMaker/

**Documentation**

http://www.videojs.com/docs/tracks/